# How to align flex items (bars) on top and bottom of page, with content in the middle

Tags: html, css

Considering the following CSS/HTML block to build my screen layout, using flex, I need:

- NAV BAR in the topmost
- TITLE BAR in the topmost, under NAVBAR
- COMMAND BAR in the very bottom
- STATUS BAR in the bottom, above COMMAND BAR
- Content: CHART and GAUGE in the middle, using all available height and width

Like:

```
|-----------------------------------|
|             NAVBAR                |
|-----------------------------------|
|           TITLE BAR               |
|-----------------------------------|
|                                   |
|             ↑                     |
|  <-  CONTENT (CHART + GAUGE) ->   |
| (fill remaining height and width) |
|             ↓                     |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|-----------------------------------|
|         STATUS BAR                |
|-----------------------------------|
|         COMMAND BAR               |
|-----------------------------------|
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backgroud-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.status {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chart {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 4;
  background-color: green;
}

.gauge {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    NAV BAR
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    TITLE BAR
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="blocks">
      <div class="chart">
        CHART
      </div>
      <div class="gauge">
        GAUGE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status">
    STATUS BAR
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    COMMAND BAR
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I'm having difficulties on flex behaviour... How can I fix it?

Comment: put a `justify-content:center` in blocks and add specific `width` to chart and gauge. You have a lot of flex you don't need also.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what this is what you're after but you need to add height to the `html` and `body` element so the container can take that height, then I would make your content div flex so the blocks can grow to fill it

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display:flex;
}

.status {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.chart {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 4;
  background-color: green;
  
  /* add this if you want the content centering */
  align-items:center;
}

.gauge {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: brown;
  
  /* add this if you want the content centering
  align-items:center; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    NAV BAR
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    TITLE BAR
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="blocks">
      <div class="chart">
        CHART - vertically centered with align-items
      </div>
      <div class="gauge">
        GAUGE - top aligned
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status">
    STATUS BAR
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    COMMAND BAR
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. All you need to do is change the `height` property in the `.container` to `100vh` from `100%`. The difference is that `100%` will make the container as high as the content within it, while the `100vh` will make the container fill the height of the viewport. I would also add some basic CSS resets such as removing all margins and paddings from the `body`and adding the `box-sizing: border-box` rule to all the elements (`*`), to make sure that the width of the "boxes" are not stretched out when adding margins, paddings, and borders.

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: 
  border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  backgroud-color: grey;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.status {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.chart {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 4;
  background-color: green;
}

.gauge {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    NAV BAR
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    TITLE BAR
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="blocks">
      <div class="chart">
        CHART
      </div>
      <div class="gauge">
        GAUGE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status">
    STATUS BAR
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    COMMAND BAR
  </div>
</div>
```